# How can I fix ExactlyOneOf: foo references unknown attribute (bar) at part (bar) from terraform-plugin-sdk?

Tags: go, terraform

Some context: I'm in the process of writing my own TF provider with the following schema:

```
func Provider() *schema.Provider {
    log.Printf("[INFO] Creating Cool Provider")
    return &schema.Provider{
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            ...
            "foo": {
                Type:         schema.TypeString,
                Optional:     true,
                Default:      "bar",
                ExactlyOneOf: []string{"bar"},
            },
        },
        ConfigureContextFunc: providerConfigure,
        ResourcesMap: map[string]*schema.Resource{
            ...
        },
    }
}
```

When I build it and run `tf plan` I run into:

```
│ Internal validation of the provider failed! This is always a bug
│ with the provider itself, and not a user issue. Please report
│ this bug:
│ 
│ 1 error occurred:
│       * ExactlyOneOf: foo references unknown attribute (bar) at part (bar)
```

which seems to be triggering from `terraform-plugin-sdk`: [link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/5f0e47111e779cb308990590c18d0ed547f0dd37/helper/schema/schema.go#L890). E.g., when I comment out `ExactlyOneOf` part, there're no errors for `tf plan` and it outputs the plan as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, the attribute `foo` is referencing another undefined attribute `bar` in its schema struct. You currently have no other attribute `bar` defined according to your displayed code, so you would need to define it or reference a defined attribute.

If you added an attribute `bar` like the following:

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
  ...
  "foo": {
    Type:         schema.TypeString,
    Optional:     true,
    Default:      "bar",
    ExactlyOneOf: []string{"bar"},
  },
  "bar": {
    Type:     schema.TypeBool,
    Optional: true,
    Default:  false,
  },
},
```

then this would fix your code. Note in the schema struct documentation for `ExactlyOneOf`:

```
// ExactlyOneOf is a set of schema keys that, when set, only one of the
// keys in that list can be specified. It will error if none are
// specified as well.
ExactlyOneOf  []string
```

Comment: When I copy your exact piece of code, I can see `│ "foo": only one of `bar,foo` can be specified, but `bar,foo` were specified.` when running `terraform plan`.

Comment: @AlexIvanov Yes, that would be the effect of the code that you wrote for `foo`. If you do not want that functionality, then you would write different code for the provider schema for `foo`, especially around your use of `ExactlyOneOf`. If the functionality of your code is still unclear, then I would recommend asking another question about that topic.

Comment: Accepted the answer! How would you recommend asking that new question? I guess I'd be happy with whatever just to make it compile (e.g., removing optional / default) if that makes sense?

Comment: According to your comment, it is your acceptance test for the provider that is failing. You would need to share the acceptance test for the provider in parallel with the provider code for us to assist with debugging.

Comment: I don't really have any tests in my repo.